# hashset input java

Tags: java, hashset

Im working on the question below and am quite close but in line 19 and 32 I get the following error and cant figure it out.

> foreach not applicable to expression type
>           for (String place: s)

**Question:**

> Tax inspectors have available to them two text files, called unemployed.txt and taxpayers.txt, respectively. Each file contains a collection of names, one name per line. The inspectors regard anyone who occurs in both files as a dodgy character. Write a program which prints the names of the dodgy characters. Make good use of Java’s support for sets.

**My code:**

```
class Dodgy {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();

    Scanner sc1 = null;
try {sc1 = new Scanner(new File("taxpayers.txt"));} 
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){};
while (sc1.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc1.nextLine();
    String s = line;
    for (String place: s) {
        if((hs.contains(place))==true){
            System.out.println(place + " is a dodgy character.");
    hs.add(place);}
    }   
}

    Scanner sc2 = null;
try {sc2 = new Scanner(new File("unemployed.txt"));} 
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){};
while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc2.nextLine();
    String s = line;
    for (String place: s) {
        if((hs.contains(place))==true){
            System.out.println(place + " is a dodgy character.");
    hs.add(place);}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to iterate  over "each string within a string" - what does that even mean?

It feels like you *only* need to iterate over each line in each file... you don't need to iterate *within* a line.

Secondly - in your first loop, you're only looking at the first file, so how could you possibly detect dodgy characters?

I would consider abstracting the problem to:

- Write a method to read a file and populate a hash set.
- Call that method twice to create two sets, then find the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach is applicable for only [`java.lang.Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) types. Since String is not, so is the error.

If your intention is to iterate characters in the string, then replace that "s" with "s.toCharArray()" which returns you an array that is `java.lang.Iterable`.